# Start and stop Tomcat via SSH on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab-ci, tomcat9

I have a Tomcat webserver running on an Ubuntu machine. How can I restart the server via SSH from gitlab-ci?

I am deploying various war & jar files to the server via ssh on gitlab-ci and need to restart the Tomcat server in some cases.

I tried using the tomcatctl command:

```sh
> ssh user@remote_ip tomcatctl stop
> bash: tomcatctl: command not found

> ssh user@remote_ip bash "tomcatctl stop"
> bash: tomcatctl: No such file or directory
```

I also tried writing a shell script and call it via ssh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
tomcatctl stop
```

```
> ssh user@remote_ip './stopTomcat.sh'
> ./stopTomcat.sh: line 2: tomcatctl: command not found
```

It looks like it is executing the remote script on the client side instead of the remote server. 
When I open a terminal on the server all the commands and script are working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It's mostly depending how your tomcat is installed and what's its version.

Following this [page](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/), you can install tomcat 9 and configure a service with systemd.

On gitlab-ci.yml, just stop the service remotely with :

```
stop_tomcat_job:
  script:
    - ssh tomcat@${SERVER} "sudo systemctl stop tomcat" > /dev/null 2>&1
```